# what are the best tips on how to market yourself for both academia and industry

Tags: computer-science, career-path, job-search, self-promotion

I have a phd in computer science and I am applying for academic jobs. However, my specialization within CS is currently getting so much attention from the industry. I don't want to waste opportunities for collaborations and consultations with industry. 
so what are the best tips to market yourself for both academia and industry? having a personal website? what to include in it ? and are there specific academic platforms that I need to be on to reach industry?

Answer (score 5):

After you get an academic position, you can get in touch with people from the research branch of the companies that interest you. Doing it before you get a job may not get you as much attention.

You can do this kind of networking at conferences (both academic or more engineering related ones, such as Strata, QCon, StrangeLoop, Grace Hopper, ...).

You can also write directly to a research scientist in the company, mentioning that you work on problems X and Y and you think they are interesting for the company and would love to talk more, and you are also willing to give a talk. People at companies like it (source: I'm a research scientist at a company).

A young CS academic who wants to be visible must have an up-to-date website with all their publications, CV, links to github or other software repositories, a news section with list of upcoming talks/travels, and so on. Thus, get a website and keep it up to date. Exactly as you do with your CV.

You may want to be on Twitter and tweet about your work, and be part of the conversation. Please have a mostly-work-related-only handle.

By the way, if you get an academic position, think about postponing the start date to spend some months at a company. Doing this can have a beneficial effect both in the short and in the long term (networking, source of problems, source of funding, ...).

Comment: I like your answer. // Do you want to say anything about the rest of OP's question?  *having a personal website? what to include in it ? and are there specific academic platforms that I need to be on to reach industry?*

Comment: Apparently he does